# Hosting JSON Files for Mobile Application

Tags: json, mobile, hosting

I am creating a mobile application using swift for my organization. The application reads in data in JSON format to populate the information that gets displayed on the application. I already have a method to generate the JSON files, but I need somewhere to host the actual files. I have an AWS account and an instance running, this is where I initially was hosting my JSON files but I got an email from AWS saying that having the app constantly grab the JSON files that I stored on the site resembled scanning behaviour, which is not allowed apparently. So I was wondering where I could host JSON files so that my mobile app can read in the information it needs. The biggest thing that I need is that I can host it with a static URL that I can keep calling with my app.

I was thinking of potentially putting the files on an AWS bucket with read permissions and having those get accessed, but since AWS already complained about me doing something like that I'm iffy. I was also thinking of putting the JSON files on Github, but again I'd hate to get an email from github telling me that they don't like that an application keeps grabbing the data.

For background, the app essentially has a hardcoded URL that grabs the JSON data and parses it. I didn't do an api because an API takes some time to grab all the information that doesn't really change that often, it's much easier to generate the JSON files locally and just post them online somewhere. The information on it can be read by anyone too it's not private or anything.

Message from AWS:

> Hello,
>
> We've received a report(s) that your AWS resource(s)
>
> *information*
>
> has been implicated in activity which resembles scanning remote hosts on the internet for security vulnerabilities. Activity of this nature is forbidden in the AWS Acceptable Use Policy (https://aws.amazon.com/aup/). We've included the original report below for your review.
>
> Please take action to stop the reported activity and reply directly to this email with details of the corrective actions you have taken. If you do not consider the activity described in these reports to be abusive, please reply to this email with details of your use case.
>
> If you're unaware of this activity, it's possible that your environment has been compromised by an external attacker, or a vulnerability is allowing your machine to be used in a way that it was not intended.
>
> We are unable to assist you with troubleshooting or technical inquiries. However, for guidance on securing your instance, we recommend reviewing the following resources:
>
> *I'm new so it won't let me post links but they attached a couple help links*
>
> If you require further assistance with this matter, you can take advantage of our developer forums:
>
> *more links I can't have*
>
> Or, if you are subscribed to a Premium Support package, you may reach out for one-on-one assistance here:
>
> *link*
>
> Please remember that you are responsible for ensuring that your instances and all applications are properly secured. If you require any further information to assist you in identifying or rectifying this issue, please let us know in a direct reply to this message.
>
> Regards,
> AWS Abuse
>
> Abuse Case Number:

Comment: if you want to stay with Amazon, S3 would be service to use. Maybe you could use a CDN (Cloudfront for amazon).

Comment: so if I do an s3 bucket do you think they'll be ok with that? That's what my original thought was but I didn't want them to get mad at me for doing it again

Comment: S3 is made to serve static content (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) (but be careful to the request/bandwidth rates!)

Comment: When you say "I didn't do an api because an API takes some time to grab all the information that doesn't really change that often", how often is not that often? Would it not be better for the app to do a cursory version check of the hosted info, and if the locally stored version is older, get the file and always read from the locally stored version of the file. This is better data usage, server usage than getting the JSON data every time you need some information from it.

Comment: Try accessing the data through the AWS SDK instead of via a URL. You should definitely reply to Amazon so they don't close your account

Comment: yeah that's essentially what I'm doing now it just takes forever that first time, but after it pulls the information once it doesn't take in the new file if it's not new. It's more of where I can have the file hosted for that first time that is the issue. It changes maybe once a week or so

Answer (score 1):

Using an AWS EC2 instance to host static files (which is what it sounds like you were doing?) is pretty standard and I suspect that this is not what Amazon is complaining about. More likely, your instance has been infected by some sort of software which is causing it to request many files from other random servers on the web ("scanning for remote vulnerabilities"). You should check that you have not accidentally publicly posted your AWS credentials (in any form), and consider wiping the instance and resetting it. And of course reply to the email explaining this to AWS.